# Jenkins projects pointing to same Mercurial repo do not share source

Tags: mercurial, jenkins

I am using Jenkins for our build server. I have multiple projects using the same Mercurial (Hg) repository and want to avoid each project cloning it's own local repo to build from (since the repo is rather large). This is supposed to be possible via Jenkins and the Mercurial plugin.

In my Mercurial plugin configuration I have checked both "Use Repository Caches" and "Use Repository Sharing". In each project, the same repository location (a network location specified via IP address) is listed.

However, each project still seems to want to create a clone of the repository. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In our setup (using Jenkins 1.506), I've defined a custom workspace under the Advanced Project Options for each of my builds, typically at `[project]\repo` and then build from there into a `\build\` folder.

If you define the custom workspace for each Jenkins project to point to the same shared custom workspace using the same source for the repo it will reuse what is already there.

I've not tested this, but I would assume that under this setup, it is important to prevent concurrent builds from occurring in the same working directory. Bad things would follow.

As a followup question: What is your rationale for not wanting each build to have its own source code?

Comment: To address the follow-up question, I suppose it comes from wanting to keep things as simple as possible and also preserving disk space. Cloning the entire repository takes up significant disk space and when I'm building each project for ~8 different permutations of settings (x86 or x64, VS2008 or VS2010) that tends to add up. All of these permutations rely on the exact same source code, so why create all these clones? It works, but it takes up an enormous amount of disk space.

Comment: ... it also lengthens the Jenkins build process, since each repo has to be updated when a change is made. I've also witnessed that Jenkins and hg can be finicky and sometimes the Hg plugin decides that a clone is necessary instead of a pull. When you have to do a clone many times, that takes a very long time.